# How to remove missing values from a dataframe when it's defined in various ways ('NONE', None, 'EMPTY')?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I have the following dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame({"name": ['Alfred', 'NONE', 'Catwoman'],
              "toy": [np.nan, 'Batmobile', 'EMPTY'],
              "kuku": [None, 8, 0]})
```

Now I want to remove all missing values - None or 'NONE' or 'EMPTY. How can I instruct pandas to remove variants of missing data: None, NONE and 'EMPTY' and any other variant (which is predefined as such)?

Comment: What do you mean by remove them? Do you mean remove the row/column if any field has it in the field/row?

Comment: Yep I have a setting that tells me what is considered Null or None.
It can be kuku, EMPTY, bubu anything. I want to remove these entries. @ArchAngelPwn

Answer (score 1):

```
df.replace('NONE', np.nan).dropna()

       name    toy  kuku
2  Catwoman  EMPTY   0.0
```

if you just want to replace all those:

```
df.replace({'NONE':np.nan, 'EMPTY':np.nan, 'None':np.nan})

       name        toy  kuku
0    Alfred        NaN   NaN
1       NaN  Batmobile   8.0
2  Catwoman        NaN   0.0
```

then you can use `.dropna(axis = )` to drop the na values

Comment: What if my empty value will be a [] or {}? @onyambu

Comment: @SteveS that means there is atleas one NA in every row/column. You should consider imputing them instead of throwing the whole observation/variable